# Whta is the diference in between google maps API and Restrict key?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

When we create Google Maps API key for Android Application.We can easily generate a API key by choosing the project Create credentials-->API key.There is option for RESTRICT key for which we have to give SHA1 with package name.What is the difference in betwwen it? And which one to follow?

Answer (score 0):

For example, Restrict to android app, only application with specific sha1 and packagename can use your api key, similar to iOS apps (only specific bundle identifiers), IP address, web url. You can reduce the impact of a compromised API key.

So, you should create different api key for each platform

Refer to the link below: https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

`API key` is a unique string that allow google to identify who is requesting access to platform and verify that they have permission to do so.

`Restrict key` is optional but highly recommended since it helps  to keep your account secured prevent malicious user for your project.
You can assign any number of restriction to the API key for your security purpose and it depends on your project whether to apply restriction or not.

There are 4 type of Application restriction:

1. Http refers:- It will be used to only allow request that originate from the particular website or web app.
2. IP Address:- This restriction allow call from specific IP address.
3. Android App:- This type of restriction only allow calls that originate from Android application.You need to specify package name and SHA-1 key.
4. iOS App:- It only allow request that originate from iOS application

There is also option for API restriction which allow you to specify the API's that can be called using key.